# reading a bin file in a chunk and find out a specific value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code is not working to find a specific value in a bin file and it is taking much longer time compared to the other code.

```
with open(fileName, mode='rb') as f:
    x = os.stat(fileName).st_size
    y = int(x/4)
    print('x,y:', x, y)
    for i in range(0, y, 4):
        x = st.unpack('<I', f.read(4))
        if x == int("00000050", 16):
            print("loc:")
```

But following code is working. I am curious what I am doing wrong in the above code?

```
        with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
            b = f.read()
            np_data = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.uint16)
            findIndex = np.where(np_data == int("00000050", 16))
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of 'danger points' in your first code snippet.
1.) in line 2 you define `x = os.stat(fileName).st_size`, in line 5 you redefine `x = st.unpack('<I', f.read(4))`.  While this may not be illegal or cause compiler issues, since x is within the scope of the while loop, it is not good practice to reassign a variable like this and it can, at a minimum, cause problems understanding your code later on.

2.) You are reading the file 4 bytes at a time, which I would imagine is much slower than the approach taken in the second code snippet, which reads the entire file.

3.) In the last line of your first code snippet, you `print("loc:")` and you probably want to do something like `print("loc:", x)`

4. Using the numpy library to find the index is quicker than looping through, since numpy is optimized for that type of search.

To at least make your first snippet work, you could try:

```
with open(fileName, mode='rb') as f:
    x = os.stat(fileName).st_size
    y = int(x/4)
    print('x,y:', x, y)
    ptr = 0
    while True:
        itm = f.read(4)
        if itm == b'':
            break
        ptr += 4
        if st.unpack('<I', itm) == int("00000050", 16):
            print("loc:", ptr)
```